# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/media/Image android/firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm beginner in android with firebase,I want to display a table in a `listView`. My table `poster` contains three fields: `image`,`status` and `username`. I tried this code but I had this error, I searched in stackoverflow but I didn't find this type of error, I think that the problem in the `image` field, thanks.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/media/Image
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getPublicFieldsRecursive(Class.java:846)
at java.lang.Class.getFields(Class.java:829)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg$zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzi(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zze(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)

 at com.example.root.guidetouristique.PosteGestion$1.onChildAdded(PosteGestion.java:36)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbox.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZV(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.media.Image
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Native Method) 
at java.lang.Class.getPublicFieldsRecursive(Class.java:846) 
at java.lang.Class.getFields(Class.java:829) 
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg$zza.<init>(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzi(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zze(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source) 
at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source) 
at com.example.root.guidetouristique.PosteGestion$1.onChildAdded(PosteGestion.java:36)
```

My code in `PosteGestion.java`:

```
 @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Post p = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        if(p!=null){
            affichage.add(p);
        }
        else{
            DR=FBD.getReference();
            return;

    }
    }
```

Post.java

```
public class Post {
public  Image image;
public  String userName;
public  String imagePost;
public  String status ;

public Post(String userName, String imagePost, String status) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.imagePost = imagePost;
    this.status = status;
}

public Post(Image image, String userName, String imagePost, String status) {
    this.image = image;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.imagePost = imagePost;
    this.status = status;

}

public Post(String userName, String status) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.status = status;
}

public Post() {
    this.image=null;
    this.imagePost=null;
    this.userName=null;
    this.status=null;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Post{" +
            "image=" + image +
            ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
            ", imagePost='" + imagePost + '\'' +
            ", status='" + status + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the contents of Post.java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Post.java` class is referencing the class `android.media.Image`.  As you can see in the [javadoc for Post](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.html), it was added in API level 19 (Kit Kat).

Likely what's happening is you're running your code on an emulator or device that is at a lower API level, which means the class is not available.

Is `android.media.Image` really what you want to store in your Post object?  The Firebase SDK won't be able to load and store that field to the database anyway.

Comment: It's true, I used an emulator API 16, I'm downloading a new version with API 19